# Do I need to keep Enconeg's Ring?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

Today I noticed that I have a ring called "Enconeg's Ring" in my inventory. It's white, and has the following description:

> A wedding ring owned by Enconeg Holn, a crazy fisherman of Ettinmere. It looks valuable.

Since it has no stats and is white, I think I can sell it. I'm not sure if I'll need it later on in the game though. Is it safe to sell this ring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I remember correctly, Enconeg gives that to you for saving him from his "nymph" bride.

Either way, there's been a pretty easy formula to this throughout the game so far... if the game lets you sell it, you don't need it for a quest. The game won't let you sell or junk quest items for incomplete quests, and also doesn't seem to count them against your inventory space.

Comment: So the famous 10 Tal books don't take away space from your inventory?

Comment: @Marcelo Correct.